# Getting the UserId mvc 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the A default ASP.NET MVC 4 project with an account controller that uses forms authentication. How do I get the userID of the current user? I want to display it in my view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

Thanks,
Steve